# Evaluating the derivatives of implicit function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

> Given:   $F(x,y,z)=x^2+3xy+2yz+y^2+z^2-11=0$.
>
> Does $F$ implicitly define a function $z = f(x,y)$ around the point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)=(1,2,0)$.
>
> If so determine $f_x=\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{dz}{dx}$ and $f_y=\frac{df}{dy}=\frac{dz}{dy}$ by the implicit-function theorem and evaluate them at the given point.

What I have done so far:
solving for $dz/dx$ and $dz/dy$

$$\frac{dz}{dx}= - (2x+y)/(2y+z)$$
$$\frac{dz}{dy}= (x-2z-2y)/(2y+2z)$$

but I have no clue how to evaluate this.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you  just plug the values of the variables into your calculated formulas?

BTW you did not prove properly that you can use the formulas - there is some (boring but fast) work to be done there. Hint: something about some derivative matrix being invertible.

Comment: up vote
0
down vote
accept
Well the problem is, i yet didnt understand what im supposed to do here. i watched videos about implicit functions over and over again and understand how to get the derivates but i dont know whats it about with the point. I mean, why do we kinda approximate around a point here? Why isnt it enough to take the derivates.

About plugging the values of the variables into my calculated formulas: first i dont know whether or not dz/dy is the same as fy even tho i suppose it is. But what does the number i get by doing so is telling me?.

Answer (score 0):

Let $F(x,y,z)=x^2+3xy+2yz+y^2+z^2-11=0$, then $F(1,2,0)=0.$ Now taking the appropriate derivative, $\partial F/\partial z = 2(y + z).$

Clearly $\partial F/\partial z |_{(1,2,0)} = 4 \neq 0.$

So we may write $z = f(x,y)$ locally. Now by the chain rule,

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial z} \frac{dz}{dx} = 0$$

Hence $dz/dx|_{(1,2,0)} =- \frac{2x + 3y}{2(y+z)} 
 \Big |_{(1,2,0)} = -8/4 = -2.$

Same idea for $dz/dy.$